# Using a Loadbalancer ssl terminated, how to generate links and other urls with https

Tags: asp.net, ssl, browser, termination, security-warning

I am having a problem with an old school asp.net site that has been moved behind a SSL terminated loadbalancer.   All traffic to IIS is coming from the load balancer as port 80 http traffic.  IIS is rendering all the script/image/link urls into `http://....`

The problem for us is the client browers are seeing pages with absolute URLs containing http protocol links within a `https://` page.   The browsers are warning about mixing secure and insecure content.

How can this be fixed so that the links are generated with `https://` instead of `http://`

Thanks in Advance

bille

Comment: 1) You mean that your mixed-content warnings are coming from sources like <img src="http:..."> not <a href="http:...">, Correct? 2) If the site only ever sees http requests, it's logical that it would use http. 3) Is there anything wrong with explicitly updating the sources to use https?

Comment: All the original sources are relative paths preceeded with a tilde charachter.   IIS is replacing the tilde with absolute paths beginning with the request protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved our issue.   The problem turned out to be the load balancer configuration.   The client is very compartmentalized and denied us access to the LB swearing that the config was correct.   After proving to them that telnetting into 443 was being blocked for some stuff we were allowed access to the LB.  In addition to just being set up wrong (cut and paste) the LB url rewrite rules were messed up.   Fixing those all is good.